# Can MDM on iOS restrict which WiFi networks are accessible?

Tags: wifi, mobile, ios

I'm evaluating MDM solutions for iOS devices that need to be restricted in what WiFi networks they can attach to.  It would be great if I could only allow connections to Networks A and B and ban all others, but I'd settle for shutting down connections to networks that have a captive portal.

Any idea if iOS exposes WiFi to the MDM solutions out there like MobileIron and AirWatch?